field define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner interface
I have got this error . when I try to query
define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner interface

This is my model struct.
type SkuDetails struct {
    SkuID       string  `json:"id"`
    SkuTitle    string  `json:"title"`
    SkuPrice    float64 `json:"price"`
    SkuBarcode  string  `json:"barcode"`
    SkuIsActive bool    `json:"is_active"`
}

// list all Skus for each category.
type SkusByCategoryId struct {
    SkuID        string       `json:"sku_id"`
    CategoryId   string       `json:"category_id"`
    CategoryName string       `json:"category_name"`
    SkuDetails   []SkuDetails `json:"sku_details"`
}


And this is my query code for SkusByCategoryId.
Table(model.TableNameSku).
Joins("INNER JOIN categories cg ON category_id = cg.id ").
Where("category_id = ?", category_id).
Scan(&skusInCategory).Error

and I want result look like this
{
category_id : "213534712"
category_name : "something"
sku_details : [
{
        SkuID  :   "" 
    SkuTitle :   ""
    SkuPrice  :  ""
    SkuBarcode : ""
    SkuIsActive : ""
}
]


Use json.Marshal to handle structs, where SkuDetails is handled specifically (using reflection to get member names)
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type SkuDetails struct {
    SkuID       string  `json:"id"`
    SkuTitle    string  `json:"title"`
    SkuPrice    float64 `json:"price"`
    SkuBarcode  string  `json:"barcode"`
    SkuIsActive bool    `json:"is_active"`
}

// list all Skus for each category.
type SkusByCategoryId struct {
    SkuID        string       `json:"sku_id"`
    CategoryId   string       `json:"category_id"`
    CategoryName string       `json:"category_name"`
    SkuDetails   []SkuDetails `json:"sku_details"`
}

func structToMap(data interface{}) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(data)
    t := reflect.TypeOf(data)

    if v.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("input data is not a struct")
    }

    result := make(map[string]interface{})

    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        field := t.Field(i)
        jsonKey := field.Tag.Get("json")
        if jsonKey == "" {
            jsonKey = field.Name
        }
        result[jsonKey] = v.Field(i).Interface()
    }

    return result, nil
}

//Implement a similar json.Marshal
func skusByCategoryIdToJson(data SkusByCategoryId) (string, error) {
    //result := make(map[string]interface{})
    
    // Use tag as the key for the SkusByCategoryId field
    categoryMap, err := structToMap(data)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    // Handle the SkuDetails field specifically
    if details, ok := categoryMap["sku_details"]; ok {
        var detailList []map[string]interface{}
        detailsSlice, _ := details.([]SkuDetails)
        for _, detail := range detailsSlice {
            detailMap := make(map[string]interface{})
            v := reflect.ValueOf(detail)
            t := reflect.TypeOf(detail)
            for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
                field := t.Field(i)
                detailMap[field.Name] = v.Field(i).Interface()
            }
            detailList = append(detailList, detailMap)
        }
        categoryMap["sku_details"] = detailList
    }

    jsonData, err := json.Marshal(categoryMap)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return string(jsonData), nil
}

func main() {
    details := []SkuDetails{
        {
            SkuID:       "123",
            SkuTitle:    "Example Product 1",
            SkuPrice:    19.99,
            SkuBarcode:  "1234567890123",
            SkuIsActive: true,
        },
        {
            SkuID:       "456",
            SkuTitle:    "Example Product 2",
            SkuPrice:    29.99,
            SkuBarcode:  "1234567890456",
            SkuIsActive: false,
        },
    }

    skusByCategory := SkusByCategoryId{
        SkuID:        "sku123",
        CategoryId:   "cat456",
        CategoryName: "Example Category",
        SkuDetails:   details,
    }

    jsonStr, err := skusByCategoryIdToJson(skusByCategory)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("JSON:", jsonStr)
}

